# E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full

Tags: ros

I want to install ROS on my Xubuntu 16.04, Xenial Xerus. I have followed the ROS's site instruction: http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu, and did the following: First, setup my sources.list:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`

Second, set up keys:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116`

Then, make sure my package is up-to-date:

`sudo apt-get update`

Last, try to install ROS jade:

`sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full`

And get this error:

`E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full`

Where did I go wrong, and how can I get ROS (any version is ok) running on my Xubuntu 16.04?

Comment: a good command to know is "apt-cache search [ros]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you indicated http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu it is said that it only support 14.04 14.10 and 15.04, therefore i don't think it is available yet for the 16.04 version.
Either try to see via auto-completion if there is any other version available,
or compile from source.

You will have better answers on the ros site http://answers.ros.org/question/226098/ros-on-ubuntu-xenial-1604/

Comment: Thanks, follow your link, i found ROS Kinetic Kame. which supported for Ubuntu 16.04, is scheduled release on May 2016. It's still in beta now: [http://wiki.ros.osuosl.org/kinetic/Installation](http://wiki.ros.osuosl.org/kinetic/Installation)